# Solving an equation to find an inverse function: $x=(e^{y}-e^{-y})/2$

Tags: functions

I'm trying to find and inverse function and I reached the equation $x=(e^{y}-e^{-y})/2$

How do I solve it for $y$?

Thanks!

Comment: $y = \sinh^{-1} (x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you multiply through by $2 e^{y}$ on both sides to get

$$e^{2 y} - 2 x e^{y} - 1 = 0$$

Solve for $e^{y}$:

$$e^y = x \pm \sqrt{x^2+1}$$

and get

$$y = \log{\left ( x \pm \sqrt{x^2+1} \right ) }$$

Which sign to use?  If $y$ is real, then of course use the positive sign.  This is, of course, $\sinh^{-1} x$.

Comment: Oh seems so simple now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Besides to @rlgordonma's answer note that we can write $x=\frac{e^{y}-e^{-y}}{2}$ as $x=\sinh(y)$. So $y=\text{arcsinh}(x)$ on a proper interval.

Comment: Indeed! :^) $\quad +1$